# mediaelement.js Wordpress play / pause button not showing

Tags: wordpress, mediaelement.js

http://mylifeisamess.com/audio-test/

I am using the audio player, the play/pause button does not appear in any of my browsers. Any idea why?

Wordpress 3.5.1 Genesis 1.9.1  Studiopress theme: Lifestyle
Mac OSx 10.7.5 Firefox 19.0.2
Safari 6.0.x
Google Chrome 26.0.1410.43

And what can I do to fix it?

Comment: I just "fixed" it -- I edited the mediaelementplayer.css file rule for: .mejs-controls .mejs-button button -- I changed the background image from "controls.svg" to "controls.png" -- and it works!  Apparently my server doesn't allow .svg as a file type. Since I don't know how to edit that setting, I decided to change the .css instead. All set!  Thanks!

Comment: Can you post it as answer and accept please?

Answer (score 4):

You may need to associate the mime type with the extension for the svg file.

Add these lines to your .htaccess file and the browser should start displaying the images correctly:

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz
```

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue with a wordpress version 4.7.1 and Internet Explorer 11.
the server / file-serving wasn't the issue, it wasn't an apache server. dunno what the problem was, but putting z-index solved the issue for me:

in my theme css i wrote

```
.mejs-controls .mejs-button button {
    z-index: 10;
}
```

the used theme was coded by me and i didn't change anything from the original wordpress mediaelement player..

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add to this thread for posterity.  This plugin was brought into the WordPress core, but that has not fixed the problem/conflict with some servers/hosts that do not recognize the svg file type.  As I write this wp 3.7.1 is out and this plugin is on 2.10.3 (although that numbering convention also changed a while back, for example I just upgraded the plugin from 2.9.1 -> 2.10.3 not intuitive.)

Simply adding the code

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz
```

to the htaccess file didn't work, but re-installing (4 times actually) the plugin yet again after adding it to the htacess file and clearing the cache did get it.

this is a very annoying issue until you can zero in on what is causing the play pause button to be hidden.